# Ubuntu software ubdater

Tags: updates

When I Update Using Software updater it up dates the snaps on my system
the snap folder is growing quite large eating up disc free space is there a gui base cleaner
that can remove old snaps even core ones ?

Done Most of the Cleaning Tricks On Ubuntu That I Could?

Ubuntu  20.04.2 LTS

Comment: What is "quite large"? Will still be only a faction of your disk space. Snap automatically cleans after a certain period, so it does not grow forever.

Comment: Does the software center not offer this functionality? I thought it did, if not, you can try the dedicated snap store app https://snapcraft.io/snap-store but I never used it. I don't really see any dedicated gui for this.

Comment: A gui package you might consider is `Stacer` from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Please show us a screenshot or other output of Software Updater offering to download/update snaps. That software is apt-only. Snapd might be refreshing snaps at the same time, but that is coincidental.

Comment: In Disc Usage The Snap Area Grew From One Gig To About  3 Gig Usage

Answer (score 0):

With **Stacer**, you can make a system diagnosis to check your CPU, memory, and disk usage, wipe cache, start-up apps, and uninstall apps. It contains a dashboard with general system information, system cleaner, startup app, and services manager, and an uninstaller.

To install stacer go to https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer/releases and download the deb package.